# How headless chrome like python requests low cpu usage?

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests, google-chrome-headless

In my situation, a website ("example.com") in busy time will redirect to "busy page"(busy.example.com).
LOOP:
When redirected to "busy page", i "get" back to ("example.com") until I go in without "Busy Page" and get cookies.

When I doing this looping , numbers of headless chrome let me cpu usage 100%.
Python requests doing this looping , cpu usage is very low but it not support js redirect like browser.

How can i solve this problem?
Can I let the headless chrome no render ?

Comment: Please care to rephrase your question in clear English, so many errors one simply couldn't not understand.

Comment: You can do the redirect with requests, just parse out the redirect url and follow it.